# Boot looping Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i

Tags: boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-ace

I sent my broken phone to repairs, and they lost it. So I'm awaiting a replacement and in the meantime, I have a bog-standard non-smart phone. My mum very kindly said I could borrow her Samsung Galaxy Ace while I await the new phone. I don't know if the change in SIM cards has triggered boot looping issue.

So, I'm busy using the phone, deleting data from Facebook/whatsapp periodically because the storage on the Ace is low, then suddenly it starts boot looping. Not sure if I inadvertently cleared data from somewhere I shouldn't.

I have tried clearing the partition cache and factory restoring with no luck.

I followed some instructions to download Odin (not the latest version but 1.7 or something such), set it up as instructed in the particular video I was watching, but when I connected the phone to the computer it didn't connect to the program.

I tried to download a newer version of Odin, but got a virus on my computer.

I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue!